# How would you convert this bash alias to a (Windows) doskey alias?

Tags: git, bash, batch-file, npm

I'm porting some bash aliases to `doskey` batch commands, and I'm having an incredibly difficult time with one in particular.  Anyone think they can help?

The bash alias is:

```
alias gitrel='if [ -n "$(npm version patch)" ]; then git push && git push --tags; fi'
```

**Question(s)**:

- How to run and get the returned value from `npm` version patch?,
- Or how to do the control flow logic within a `doskey` command?

Comment: An alias is not a script. In fact, aliases are disabled by default inside of scripts. They are intended for interactive use.

Comment: Fair enough, I changed the title.  The point is still to have a bunch of aliases in a batch file run at the beginning of each `cmd.exe` session.

Comment: What you're doing as an alias, I would do as a bash function.  And the easiest way to convert bash functions to MS-DOS is probably to make separate batch files for each one.  Why not make a small library of batch files, put them in a reasonable location, then add that location to your `%PATH%` ?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis for all of the other aliases I'm porting, I've managed to do it with a `doskey` oneliner, even separating multiple commands with `$t` with no problem.  I haven't tried anything for this particular one because I can't figure out how to run and get the returned value from `npm version patch`, or how to do the control flow logic within a `doskey` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with a FOR/F loop, but only if npn will only print one or no line, if it can print two lines this code will push multiple times.

```
doskey alias=for /F "delims=" %a in ('npm version patch') do @( git push && git push --tags )
```